# for command is executed only for the first value when a label is inside

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the script

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%folder%*.txt" /b /s') do (
    set s=%%i
    set s=!s:%folder%=!
    set new_s=!s:\=!
    if "x!new_s!" NEQ "x!s!" (
        :ProcessListSource
        For /f "tokens=1* delims=\" %%A in ("!s!") do (
            if "%%A" NEQ "" ( 
                if "!Folder1!" NEQ "" (
                    Set Folder1=!Folder1!\!Name!
                )else (
                    Set Folder1=!Name!
                )
                Set Name=%%A
            )
            if "%%B" NEQ "" (
                set s=%%B
                goto :ProcessListSource
            )
        )
        echo Folder is: !Folder1!
        echo Name is: !Name!
        echo ---------------------
    ) else (
        echo Not a folder !s!
    )
)
```

but it does not work as I would have expected:
The first for is executed only once and also the last echo is printed on the screen.

Given a folder I need the files from subfolders without the given folder and than split them into the folder and file

Ex: folder=C:\test

The for would give me the file C:\test\test1\test2\t.txt

And I need test1\test2 and t.txt

Answer (score 2):

`GOTO` breaks your `FOR /F`  \ `IF` context and they can be executed only once.

More simple example:

```
@echo off

for /l %%S in (1=1=5) do (
    echo %%S
    goto :inner_label
    rem
    :inner_label
    rem

)
```

This will print only `1` . Do you really need the `GOTO` here?

Answer (score 1):

When the parser reads your code, all the code inside your for loop is "considered" as only one command that is readed, parsed and executed. As stated in the npocmaka answer, any `goto` call takes you out of this "line" of code, ending the process of the for loop.

This is a alternative. Use `pushd` + `xcopy /l /s` commands to generate a list of the relative paths of the files.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder=%cd%"

    pushd "%folder%"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('xcopy /l /s /y * "%temp%"^|findstr /vbr /c:"[0-9]"'
    ) do for /f "delims=: tokens=1,*" %%b in ("%%~a") do (
        echo [%%c] [%%~nxa]
    )
    popd
```